# Ubuntu OEM prep for distro "Manufacturer details"

Tags: oem, hardware-certification

Newly installed Ubuntu 16.04 OEM but cant distro because the system is still missing OEM Manufacturer, Make, Model and so forth. In an attempt to remedy my issue, I have attempted several different approaches such as: reinstallation, entering bios and changing settings.

sudo apt-get install hardware-lister

OEM NAME: "Provided by OEM Manufacturer"
OEM MAKE: "Provided by OEM Manufacturer"
OEM MODEL: "Provided by OEM Manufacturer"

My suspect is that OEM Manufacturer, Make, Model missing information is the culmination of issues. I think the relation to the OEM issue is that it may be ultimately missing key certs. Because when booting up, I did recognize "modesign db list ..." as well as during the nvidia installation notice "secure boot is disabled", and also preventing "Canonical-livepatch" from being enabled. My current mobo bios does not have a feature to enable/disable secure boot, its settings include UEFI, EFI and legacy. All of which have been reconfigured to remedy with no success.

So apparently, the OEM details would culminate the additional issues I am currently facing. My thought process is... In order to ensure the OEM information permanently sticks is to make those changes through a bios flash which I am not fully capable of doing yet. I hope there is another alternate method of resolving my OEM details issue.

Question:

- Is there a way to access the required information listed by "hardware-lister" to "change/modify" the OEM Manufacturer, Make, Model and so forth?
- If so, how and/or what would I need to make those changes using an app or terminal?

Please bare with me as I am fairly new to UBUNTU.

Thanks!

Comment: OEM information is changed in the BIOS, not in Ubuntu.

Comment: which virtualbox are you using virtualbox or vmware ?

Comment: I'm using live and on the problematic motherboard. It seems that my MOBO did not come with appropriate firmware keys.

Comment: Oops, sent too early. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 O.E.M  64 Bit live. I've already attempted previous versions as well as vm and also down graded to 32 bit with no success.  I've attempted multiple settings as well on my MOBO since it does not provide disable/enable secure boot.  I did find an article relating to my issue. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#SecureBoot My current read up for preparing for the worst case scenario to flash my Bios. It seems like everything is now pointing to Flashing the Bios.